# Fresh install Windows 7 from USB on machine with Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, usb, windows, dual-boot, iso

I have a Toshiba laptop l755 S5282 with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on it. About a year ago, I pulled an iso file off of DigitalRivers for Windows 7. I did a fresh install of Windows 7 from USB, then after that, I installed Ubuntu along side it. Everything is fine with system. My question: I may be selling this laptop and buying a desktop, and the buyer asked that I install Windows 7 as the only operating system on it. Does anyone have experience with doing a fresh install of Windows 7 on a machine that has Ubuntu and Windows installed? What is the safest way to go about it? Can I use the same iso from the same USB stick and just run the install prompts from boot up off usb? Will that take care of rewriting the partitions as Windows 7 on C: and the 1.46gb recovery? No more Grub menu?

I used to have Toshiba recovery partition on it, but once I saw how easy it was to do a fresh install myself, I deleted the huge 13.5GB Toshiba recovery partition and used it towards Ubuntu's partition. I just want to make sure it'll go as smoothly as before, when I was just over writing Windows by itself.

Here's a screenshot of Gparted output, to show what's on it now:
[image: Gparted image]

Comment: If you're going to sell it I'd wipe the drive using `fdisk`, just delete the partitions, and then re-install using Win7 ISO. Should go smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

As you are going to sell it, I guess you don't need the data in here. You can then run the Windows installer from the ISO you have, delete all existing partitions and install Windows with the partitions of your choice.
If you are not confortable with Windows partition manager, you could also delete everything from a live CD of Linux.